# What is the exact meaning of an "Abstract Submission Deadline"?

Tags: conference, paper-submission, abstract, deadlines

I don't know exactly the meaning of "Abstract Submission Deadline". Is this time only for an abstract, or must I send my whole paper at that time?

Comment: Where is this deadline stated?  It certainly sounds like a deadline for submitting an abstract, not a whole paper.  However, some CS conferences have "extended abstracts" which might be the length of a short paper.  I don't think there's any way to say more without knowing the context (preferably which conference you are talking about, but at least the general field).

Comment: thank you so much for your answer and help. actually i see that in many conferences such as this site :   http://cpmt.ieee.org/conferences.html     that has a tab with " Abstract Submission Date ".

Comment: Please state the field you are in. There are some fields where there is no "whole paper" to follow an abstract submission for a conference.

Answer (score 5):

It is only for an abstract. Usually, there is another one for the whole paper, clearly said.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. do you know about those sites that only hint the abstract submission date but not the submission date for whole paper? maybe after i submitted my paper they say me about the exact day of deadline?

Comment: There are no particular sites. It depends on each and every conference and the comitee behind it.